# "Have I got this job" is a common question. Do/should we have a canonical question for this?

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicates

Variants of "have I got this job?" come up about twice a day, to which the answer is almost invariably, "if you don't have anything in writing, you don't have an offer, keep looking for other jobs".

I think it would help to have a canonical question to cover this, so new questions can be marked as duplicate, saving people from answering unnecessarily.

I discovered two commonly used "duplicate candidates" which have some overlap with the scenario, but they do not cover it entirely.

1. [How do I coordinate the process of pursuing multiple job opportunities at the same time?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/111/3192)
2. [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/6018/3192)

Does the community also see the need to have such a canonical question? 
Is there already such a question?

Comment: I would definitely be on-board with this. There may be a suitable question out there already, though I don't have the time to dig around right now.

Comment: I agree.  It comes up all the time.

Comment: Perhaps you could ask a question that could become canonical.  "When do I know when I have the job?" or a variant on that.  From my personal experience it's "When you're sitting behind your desk".  I've had job offers rescinded literally the day I was supposed to start.

Comment: I like Richard's suggestion.  Hurdle 1: actual written offer.  Hurdle 2 (sometimes): background check.  Hurdle 3: sometimes stuff happens before your first day (so, as Richard said, when you're actually there).

Comment: There are occasional discussions on questions and on meta where topics are identified that could use a canonical question. This is indeed another such case. Most of the time no actual question ends up being posted and I think the main issue is scoping and defining the question to ensure that would-be answerers are aware that it's not a "real" situation and the answers should be comprehensive. Perhaps a mod-notice would be useful for them.

Comment: At the risk of self-promoting, I've asked two such questions so far ([1](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/57235), [2](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/76449)) and those turned out well in my view. They *do* tend to require a bit of extra work from the OP, especially if they hit HNQ. Perhaps it's an option to scope and define a question on meta before posting it as a CW?

Comment: i find myself typing the same thing over and over.  It's sad but it'd be easier just to ask something like "I don't get along with my boss and I'm contemplating going to HR. Is that a good idea? Why or why not?" and then just mark a bunch of dupes afterward.  :)

Comment: @ChristopherEstep the "Counter offer" one comes up frequently as well.

Comment: If you get a counter offer, ask if the quote includes the cabinets?

Comment: Personally I'd like the question to include the likelyness the employee will get hired based on which stage he/she is in. Where it would only be 100% hired once both his and the employer's autographs are written on a contract where both you and the company has a copy. I've had a brother work for almost 2 years (despite us telling him to do otherwise) without a written contract. The employer simply left the country and never paid my brother a single coin. and without a contract, he didnt have the rights for it either, despite having worked for it.

Comment: There are plenty of these already

Comment: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/31656/verbal-job-offer-confirmation-but-actual-letter-still-pending

Comment: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/46959/16

Comment: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=no+offer+letter

Comment: @keshlam you clever clever soul I had to read that three times before I caught it.

Comment: The premise is not even correct for all countries. A verbal offer stating a position title, a manager, a pay-grade or salary can be binding in some countries. (Proving it existed in the case of a disagreement is of course another story.) It's not all about the US or India.

Comment: @smci That's interesting to know. I would like to learn more. Which countries follow that? If they cannot prove the offer, how do they enforce it?

Comment: @MaskedMan: most Western European countries have higher ethical standards in business dealings than the US. I didn't say those courts would necessarily find a disputed verbal offer existed; I'm saying the companies are less likely to lie in the first place, yes even (in-house) recruiters. The reason for that is simply that word-of-mouth about bad practices gets around, also people change job less often. People have memories. To be clear I'm not saying relying on a verbal offer is generally a good idea, whoever you're dealing with. I'm saying it's less risky in some cultures.

Comment: Here's one article reflecting that for England & Wales: http://books.stuartherbert.com/getting-hired/job-offer.html

Comment: I am a bit confused by the link you shared, it explicitly states: "until you have a written job offer, you don’t have a job", which runs contrary to the point you are making here. I am not familiar with the hiring practices in Western Europe, could you please clarify? That aside, I think as @RichardU points out above, it may be better to change the canonical question to, "when do I know I have the job?", which can have several region-specific answers.

Comment: I'm for the idea, and I think the part that Migz brought in should be considered as part of the answer : no writting contract : no guarantes you will be paid or can sue your employer for non paid work.

Comment: To be honest, I don't see how people don't know the answer because there are only two possibilities IMO:

1) You have a formal written offer of employment that you have executed.
2) You have been on-boarded.

Comment: @Aithos What is obvious to you is not necessarily obvious to everyone. We get this question way too often here.

Comment: @Aithos: that's often incorrect. Consider the case of a person receiving an offer in another country, then having to move, possibly obtain a visa/work permit, and possibly front the travel/relocation costs, and possibly move their family and sell a house. And before they're even allowed to enter the destination country, they may well have to prove to immigration that the job offer exists. There are lots of well-known bait-and-switch practices that can get pulled, "the original position you were offered has already been filled, but we have this lower position that pays 40% worse".